# Send element from 2D list to excel sheet, python

Tags: python, excel, list

**It print all list items when I print it. But when I want to send data to excel, the file is empty of elements. Why?**

```
name = ['Smith','Johnson','Williams','Brown','Jones','Miller','Davis','Garcia']
age = [22 ,44, 44, 65, 64, 47, 14, 63]

person = [[name],[age]]
print(person)
with xlsxwriter.Workbook('fileName.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for row_num, data in enumerate(person):
        worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, data)
```

***OUTPUT:***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhTqL.png)

Comment: Look at the values of `data` in your loop. They're not what you think they are.

Comment: Can you explain more? @MattDMo